# Changes needed in Java Application to support Oracle RAC Fail-Over: FCF/TAF

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, failover

I have a java web-application that uses JDBC-Thin driver (Type 4) to connect to Oracle RAC.
I need to ensure that the application can take advantage of Oracle RAC failover.

So, i have two options here:
(A) Use FCF: Fast Connection Failover - this can work with existing JDBC-thin driver.
**Question: What changes do i need to make in my application "code" to get FCF to work, or simply installing ONS (Oracle Notification Service) and changing jdbc-url perhaps will take care of it ?**

(B) Use TAF: Transparent Application Failover - this requires Oracle OCI client
**Question: Will this require any Application Code changes? Or simply installing OCI client, and changing the jdbc url will take care of it?**

I have seen the relevant documentation, but cannot find a definitive answer.
Experts any advice?

Comment: Have you had any luck finding answer to these questions? Could you, please, share with me? :)